# Android Emulator started from Visual Studio not debugging at Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with all updates installed (version 17.5.1) to create a Xamarin project on a fresh Windows 11 Pro System. For this I need to test and debug my Android application in the Android Emulator. I selected everything for this in the Visual Studio installer.
During my research about the problem I also verified already that Hyper-V and the HypervisorPlatform-Feature and installed and enabled as well as the Android Emulator Hypervisor driver Tool/Extra is installed via the Android SDK and Tools program. I also setup a device in the Android Device Manager with the current latest API (Android 13 - API 33), which can be started.

What actually happens:
I start Visual Studio, load my project and wait until everything is loaded and also the background tasks are done (don't know if this is required). After verify that I am using the Debug profile, I am clicking the "play" button. The Emulator starts and loads correctly. At least it looks like. Visual Studio also build the project and states `Deploy succeeded`.
The output of the Output pane in Visual Studio confirms this:

```
Build succeeded.
Deployment was successful to pixel_5_-_api_33.
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And that's it. Nothing happens anymore. Visual Studio stops debugging and the App is not deployed to the emulated device. It does not appear in the app list.
When I check with the `adb devices` via cmd, the emulator is connected.
Cleaning the project and delete bin and obj folder also doesn't help.

Edit:
Two more infos: 1. Starting a new Project with the default template works. 2. The output of "Xamarin Diagnostics" is just this three lines

```
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[I:]:                     Looking for Android SDK...
```

Answer (score 0):

After this issue cost me a lot of time, here is what solved the issue for me:

1. Checked out the last working version from the repository.
2. Changed Target Version to Android 13 - Api 33. The app builds and starts but crashes because of outdated 3rd party libaries - but this OK, because it actually starts!
3. Updated 3rd party libraries step by step. When updateing Xamarin.Google.Android.Material to Version 1.8.0 (1.2.1.1 before) the following compile error occurs:

   ```
   error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener
   ```

So I made the class MainActivity abstract. The method already exists. Et voila - app is not starting anymore like before.

I checked how it looks like for a new app. It looks like in my project. No abstract or override of something. It is also using that library but in version 1.0.0.1. So I tried all minor versions before. All newer versions up to 1.8 have the same error. When I update the new project to the latest version it actually works...
Comparing a bit more, I figured out, that the new project is using

```
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
```

while my one is using `Android.Support.Desgin.Widget`. So I replaced my one and: Problem solved!

Comment: Yes, after 2 days I am allowed to do this ;)